# Trying to understand boolean array indexing

Tags: python, opencv

I cannot understand what this line of code is doing.

`image[harris_corners > 0.025*harris_corners.max()] = [255,127,127]`

It would be great if I can get an equivalent code.

Comment: It sets the locations where the `harris_corners` are greater than 0.025 the maximum of all `harris_corners` elements in the image to 255 red, 127 green and 127 blue.

Comment: What type of variable is `image`? A numpy array?

Comment: print `image` before the line. print `image` after the line. compare. still have a question?

Comment: @cricket_007 almost certainly a numpy array because of the opencv tag.

Comment: In that case, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 3):

I really like the numpy syntax because it's possible to understand it step by step.

In order to understand:

```
image[harris_corners > 0.025*harris_corners.max()] = [255,127,127]
```

you could try the following in a Python console:

```
harris_corners
harris_corners.max()
0.025*harris_corners.max()
harris_corners > 0.025*harris_corners.max()
image
image[harris_corners > 0.025*harris_corners.max()]
image[harris_corners > 0.025*harris_corners.max()] = [255,127,127]
image
```

At each step, try to understand what the object is, which type it is, what it represents and what changed in comparison to the previous object.

With dummy data, it becomes:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> harris_corners = np.random.randint(20, size=10)
>>> harris_corners
array([14, 18,  3,  7, 19,  2, 16, 19,  2,  3])
>>> harris_corners.max()
19
>>> harris_corners > harris_corners.max() * 0.25
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> harris_corners[harris_corners > harris_corners.max() * 0.25]
array([14, 18,  7, 19, 16, 19])
>>> harris_corners[harris_corners > harris_corners.max() * 0.25] = 99
>>> harris_corners
array([99, 99,  3, 99, 99,  2, 99, 99,  2,  3])
```

Basically, it replaces values that are larger than 25% of the maximum by 99.

In your case, elements are RGB pixels instead of integers, but the syntax and principle are the same.